How to obtain a reusable download URL for a Drive Item?
I would like to obtain a re-usable Download URL for all drive items (which are files) within a Drive.
As per document, @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl is a short lived (typically one hour) URL. I prefer not to use this as I may store the download URL in a database and fetch the file at some undetermined later point in time.
I could use the shares endpoint but this requires creating a sharing link for every drive item. This is not ideal as I don't want to create these links and then have to manage (eg delete) them.
Is there any endpoint which provides a download URL which can be accessed using expected authentication and is not short lived like the aforementioned downloadUrl?
Thanks!
